# Restclient Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException : HOST NAME

Tags: java, rest-client

i am trying to invoke rest call and have below rest high level client.

```
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "cool"));
        client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(HOST, PORT, SCHEMA))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                        return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                    }
                }));
```

i have host and port defined in application.properties file as below

```
#test/dev host elastic service url 
HOST.URL=http://go-test

#test/dev host port 
HOST.PORT=9200
  
SCHEMA=http
```

My bean property

```
@Value("${HOST.URL}")
private String HOST;

@Value("${HOST.PORT}")
private int PORT;

@Value("${SCHEMA}")
private String SCHEMA;
```

when i try to run i am getting below execption...

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://go-test
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105)
```

dont know what is causing the issue, when i try with ip, it is working perfectly.
Same host name when i try in chrome browser, it is working fine.. getting response from bacekend rest api..

```
{
  "name" : "ip",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "q",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.3",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "c",
    "build_date" : "2020-10-16T10:36:16.141335Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the host url should be `http:/go-test` and not `http://go-test`?

Comment: `HOST.URL=http:/go-test` should `HOST.URL=http://go-test`.

Comment: You are not showing how your properties are mapped to the values you pass to the `HttpHost` constructor, but from the error message HOST.URL should just be the host name.

Comment: sorry it was typo.. url is http:// go-test

Comment: can do a ping to go-test from your machine? its not working and you know the ip address of the host then make a entry in the `hosts` file.

Answer (score 1):

This code is passing a URL to code that is expecting only a hostname.

Set `HOST` to `go-test` instead of `http://go-test`.

Comment: Could you edit the question then to reflect what you're trying now and the error that you're getting. If it's still `UnknownHostException` then that must be the wrong hostname.